# Apply a match and replace function over series of rows in a dataframe in order

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Starting dataframe

```
data_start <- data.frame(marker = c("yes","yes","no","yes","no"),
                         id_out = c(5,3,1,1,7), 
                         id_new = c(6,8,9,4,2))

> data_start
  marker id_out id_new
1    yes      5      6
2    yes      3      8
3     no      1      9
4    yes      1      4
5     no      7      2
```

Add three column headers with empty columns below. Attach the starting `var1:var3` values.

```
data_start[,c("var1", "var2", "var3")] <- NA
vars <- c(5,3,1)
data_start[1, 4:6] <- vars

> data_start
  marker id_out id_new var1 var2 var3
1    yes      5      6    5    3    1
2    yes      3      8   NA   NA   NA
3     no      1      9   NA   NA   NA
4    yes      1      4   NA   NA   NA
5     no      7      2   NA   NA   NA
```

I would like to update my `var1:var3` columns by applying a function to each row where IF `marker` = `yes` AND `id_out` matches ANY of the `var1:var3`, replace any of `var1:var3` with `id_new`. I found this solution, but works for one line of code and still requires each new `var1:var3` part of the row to update.

```
data_start[1, 4:6][data_start[1, 4:6] == data_start[1,"id_out"]] <- data_start[1,"id_new"]
```

Each row also depends on using the values from the above row before again applying the function.

The final output would look like this where the rows stay unchanged when the marker = `no` and each row is subsequently updated.

```
> data_final
  marker id_out id_new var1 var2 var3
1    yes      5      6    6    3    1
2    yes      3      8    6    8    1
3     no      1      9    6    8    1
4    yes      1      4    6    8    4
5     no      7      2    6    8    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to use with any number of columns and works with base R:

```
cols <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")

for(j in 1:length(cols)) {
  var <- cols[j]
  for(i in 1:nrow(data_start)){
    if(i > 1) {
      data_start[i, var] <- data_start[i-1, var]
    }
    if(data_start[i, "marker"] == "yes" & data_start[i, var] == data_start[i,"id_out"]) {
      data_start[i,var] <- data_start[i, "id_new"]
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, finally came back to this and it works as hoped.

Answer (score 0):

This is put together very crudely cause I've got to run, but this should work.

```
data_start <- data.frame(marker = c("yes","yes","no","yes","no"),
                         id_out = c(5,3,1,1,7), 
                         id_new = c(6,8,9,4,2))

data_start[,c("var1", "var2", "var3")] <- NA
vars <- c(5,3,1)
data_start[1, 4:6] <- vars

onVars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")

for (i in 2:nrow(data_start)) {

  print(i)

  for (var in onVars) {

    if (data_start$marker[i] == "yes" & data_start$id_out[i] == data_start[i - 1, var]) {

      data_start[i, var] <- data_start$id_new[i]

    } else {

      data_start[i, var] <- data_start[i - 1, var]

    }

  }

}
```

data_start is your output.

Oops, looks like I might have left out evaluating the first row, but hopefully you can handle that yourself now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that will allow you to do this calculation even if you have more than three columns:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(marker = c("yes","yes","no","yes","no"),
                         id_out = c(5,3,1,1,7), 
                         id_new = c(6,8,9,4,2))

dt[, change := cumsum(marker == "yes")]

ref.new <- dt[marker == "yes", id_new] # Reference to values where marker is "yes"
ref.out <- dt[marker == "yes", id_out]
for (x in 1:length(ref.new)) {
  dt[, paste("var", x, sep="") := ifelse(change >= x, ref.new[x] , ref.out[x])]
}
head(dt)
#     marker id_out id_new change var1 var2 var3
#1:    yes      5      6      1    6    3    1
#2:    yes      3      8      2    6    8    1
#3:     no      1      9      2    6    8    1
#4:    yes      1      4      3    6    8    4
#5:     no      7      2      3    6    8    4
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach but it seems like you are assuming some pattern here that weren't mentioned by the OP so I'm not sure if this works by chance or this is really what's should be

Comment: I think I know what you mean.. well it is easy to change either way, I just used the most straight forward option.

Answer (score 0):

It seems difficult to find a solution without for loop and if, so here it is. I tried to change the original values with other set such as `c(1,3,1)` and the codes work fine. We can also add more variable columns if needed.

```
# Re-create the data
dt <- data.table(marker = c("yes","yes","no","yes","no"),
                 id_out = c(5,3,1,1,7),
                 id_new = c(6,8,9,4,2))
var.col <- paste0("var", 1:3)
dt[1, (var.col) := .(5,3,1)]

# Processing
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  if(i > 1) dt[i, (var.col) := as.list(dt[i-1, var.col, with = F])]
  var.i <- dt[i, var.col, with = F] %in% dt[i, id_out]
  if(dt[i]$marker == 'yes' & sum(var.i) != 0) {
    dt[i, (var.col[var.i]) := dt[i, id_new]]
  }
}
```